# Gradle does not include compile dependency using compile configuration

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I have added a compile dependency to may android project. Gradle downloads the `jar` file from the server but it does not add it to class path. Here is what I have done so far. I have added dependency,

```
compile  'com.mallaudin.android:oxygeroid-annotations:1.0.0'
```

and checked the cached path of gradle

```
C:\Users\---\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mallaudin.android\oxygeroid-annotations\1.0.0\95cdbaf882c04d8cbb891143e83af3c3f0858947
```

and it was there. This dependency adds a `@ViewFactory` annotation which I am  **not** getting currently.

I have added the **same jar** file in my `app/libs` folder and as `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` ensures, this will be added to my class path and **it works this way**.

> What's wrong with first method. Jar is there, but still I can't refer
>   to any of the classes in jar.

Comment: what does your repositories section look like?

Comment: files are available here https://dl.bintray.com/mallaudin/android/com/mallaudin/android/oxygeroid-annotations/1.0.0/